# Highest per each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

It's hard to show my actual table and data here so I'll describe my problem with a sample table and data:

```
create table foo(id int,x_part int,y_part int,out_id int,out_idx text);

insert into foo values (1,2,3,55,'BAK'),(2,3,4,77,'ZAK'),(3,4,8,55,'RGT'),(9,10,15,77,'UIT'),
                       (3,4,8,11,'UTL'),(3,4,8,65,'MAQ'),(3,4,8,77,'YTU');
```

Following is the table `foo`:

```
id x_part y_part out_id out_idx 
-- ------ ------ ------ ------- 
3  4      8      11     UTL     
3  4      8      55     RGT     
1  2      3      55     BAK     
3  4      8      65     MAQ     
9  10     15     77     UIT     
2  3      4      77     ZAK     
3  4      8      77     YTU
```

I need to select all fields by sorting the *highest* `id` of each `out_id`.
Expected output:

```
id x_part y_part out_id out_idx 
-- ------ ------ ------ ------- 
3  4      8      11     UTL     
3  4      8      55     RGT     
3  4      8      65     MAQ     
9  10     15     77     UIT
```

Using PostgreSQL.

Comment: The fastest solution depends on cardinalities, data distribution and whether you have a table with all distinct `out_id`.  Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564

Answer (score 4):

Postgres specific (and fastest) solution:

```
select distinct on (out_id) *
from foo
order by out_id, id desc;
```

Standard SQL solution using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) (second fastest)

```
select id, x_part, y_part, out_id, out_idx
from (
  select id, x_part, y_part, out_id, out_idx, 
         row_number() over (partition by out_id order by id desc) as rn
  from foo
) t
where rn = 1
order by id;
```

Note that both solutions will only return each `id` once, even if there are multiple `out_id` values that are the same. If you want them all returned, use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from foo 
where (id,out_id) in (
select max(id),out_id from foo group by out_id
) order by out_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Finding `max(val)` := finding the record for which no larger `val` exists:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 317
   FROM foo nx
   WHERE nx.out_id = f.out_id
   AND nx.id > f.id
   );
```

Comment: Nice one. `where out_id > all (select .. )` would be another variation of that.